# Solving a one-dimensional spring system using linear algebra

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, spring, linear-algebra

I'm trying to gain some intuition into how the following problem would be solved using linear algebra.

The setup of the problem is a horizontal line of 4 springs and 3 masses: alternating spring, mass, spring, mass, spring, mass, spring between two walls. I found a good picture on the last page of this pdf: http://www.math.ksu.edu/~dbski/calculus/hooke.pdf

The masses -- $m_1, m_2, m_3$ -- have a unitless value of 1.
The spring constants -- $k_1, k_2, k_3, k_4$ -- have a unitless value of 1 for $k_1, k_4$ and 2 for $k_2, k_3$.

There are three horizontal forces now applied $F_1, F_2, F_3$ at the three masses.

As the masses will move to new equilibrium positions because of these forces, we want to know the horizontal displacements of the masses: $x_1, x_2, x_3$ from their original positions.

We're supposed to write down the linear system $Ax = F$, where $x$ and $F$ are vectors and $A$ is a 3x3 matrix.

I think this corresponds in some way with Hooke's law, $F = -kx$, but I don't know how to find $A$ (we are later asked to solve for $x$ given $F = [4\ 2\ 4]^T$). I can't intuitively figure out what $A$ would even be because there are more dimensions.

Comment: How about writing down 3 equations for each mass? For example, force acting upon mass 1 will look something like that: $F_1=k_1x_1 - k_2(x_2-x_1)$ I might be wrong with signs, but that is for you to figure out. When you write 3 equations, sort them so that each will look like: $F_i=a_{1i}x_1+a_{2i}x_2+a_{3i}x_3$ and $a_{ij}$ will be elements of $A$

Comment: And additional hint to very good comment above: be aware of the fact, that displacement from equilibrium position is not the same like the displacement measured from the origin (the wall). I would suggest the simple transformation from $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ measured from the origin to $(\xi_1, \xi_2, \xi_3)$ measured from the according equilibrium point. Use $F = -k\xi$ for them and transform back to $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$. It's obviously not necessary, but you can get rid of some brackets $(x_3-x_2+x_{whatever}+...)$,

Comment: @VictorPira  am not interested enough to write it down, but is it true that real equation should look like $A\vec{x}+\vec{B}=\vec{F}$?

Comment: Yes, it should. And it realy should be only algebraic equation, cause we are looking for state of equilibrium (otherwise there would be 3 coupled differential equations of 2nd order).